# Using A Proxy With Ruby PG Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pg

I'm developing a Rails application on Heroku that needs to make callout's to our customer's databases.  We have setup a proxy to make our outbound IP address static and are now configuring our 'connection' classes to use that proxy.

My trouble is that ruby's PG gem (https://deveiate.org/code/pg/), which we use to connect to PostgreSQL like dbs doesn't have a proxy feature built in.

Does anyone know of a way to use a proxy with the Ruby PG gem (or a healthy alternative gem that has a proxy feature)?

Thanks in advance :-)